# Deploy with deployer fails on vendors

Tags: laravel, vendor, php-deployer

I try to deploy the Laravel application with deployer. The process fails.

Below you will see the responses

```
✔ Executing task deploy:shared
✔ Executing task deploy:writable
➤ Executing task deploy:vendors
✔ Executing task deploy:failed

In Client.php line 99:

  The command "cd /gopanel/sites/xxx_net/public/xaio/releases/1 && /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install --verbose --prefer-dist   
  --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader" failed.                                                                        

  Exit Code: 1 (General error)                                                                                                                  

  Host Name: xx.xxxx.net                                                                                                                  

  ================                                                                                                                              
  Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                        
  Installing dependencies from lock file                                                                                                        
  Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds                                                                                              
  Analyzed 166 packages to resolve dependencies                                                                                                 
  Analyzed 463 rules to resolve dependencies                                                                                                    
  Package operations: 103 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals                                                                                       
  Installs: symfony/polyfill-ctype:v1.11.0, phpoption/phpoption:1.5.0, vlucas/phpdotenv:v3.3.3, symfony/css-selector:v4.2.4, 
  y/psysh:v0.9.9, laravel/tinker:v1.0.8, intervention/image:2.4.2, league/glide:1.5.0, owen-it/laravel-auditing:v9.0.0, predis/predis:v1.1.1,
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Output is not enough to understand. You must run your command in verbose mode by adding `-vvv` to end of command.

Like this:

`user@local:~$ dep deploy host -vvv`